# How can I transform an incoming SOAP response into a JSON document using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3?

Tags: json, soap, transformation, esb, wso2

I would like to transform the SOAP response body to JSON using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. I found [info](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/ESB+and+JSON) on how to configure the ESB for JSON but then what?

To put it differently; I would like to have/create a transform mediator that transforms incoming SOAP/XML response into JSON (and actually it woudl be good to have a JSON2XML transform mediator too).

Should I develop is as a Groovy script mediator or Java class mediator? The best would be to have it pre-packaged with the ESB as it says it supports JSON and format transformations...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XSLT transform to do that. See [this](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample440) sample. It shows how to transform a JSON into a SOAP request and forward to the Axis2 server. Then the SOAP response from the Axis2 server will be converted into a JSON message and sent back. Before that, as you mentioned, you will have to configure ESB to support JSON like [this](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples_setup_guide.html#setupjson).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, the example doe snot work, I got `[java] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: <faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</faultstring>`.

Comment: Sorry. There's a mistake in the sample I pointed you to. Make sure endpoint address is this: `<address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11"/>` in the synapse configuration. You can modify it by navigating to `https://localhost:9443` Then Going to `Manage > Service Bus > Source view`