# JSON Message to SOAP Request in Mule

Tags: json, soap, mule

I just found this:
[How can I transform an incoming SOAP response into a JSON document using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311517/how-can-i-transform-an-incoming-soap-response-into-a-json-document-using-wso2-es)
and basically I'd like to do something similar - just in Mule:

I've got a JSON message and I'd like to transform it into a SOAP request.
The JSON message is a list of customers from Magento and I'd like to insert them via SOAP into our CRM.
Is there a documentation or example or similar on how to do something like this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3):

- Generate a CXF client for your SOAP service: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF
- Transform your JSON string in Java data structures (List and Maps) with:

  ```
  <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
  ```
- Use an `<expression-transformer>` to create the object(s) used by the SOAP operations out of the Java data structures, using the convenience of MEL syntax for map/list navigation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be, after using `<json:json-to-object-transformer/>` , extract the values and store it in variables..
Then you can use XSLT transformer, you can pass the variables value in iy and can create Dynamic SOAP request.
reference of XSLT transformer in Mule :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer